# MIPS stack frame (and "addiu" instruction confusion)

Tags: assembly, mips, disassembly, opcode

I'm new to MIPS and am trying to understand the disassembly of a function.
(EDIT: it is dynamically linked to /lib/ld-uClib.so.0 and uses some usual libc functions, so I assume it was written in C using the uClibc toolchain, and should therefore have that calling procedure and stack frame, etc.).

At the start of the function it does

```
00400824 <practice_crackme>:
  400824:   3c1c0fc0    lui gp,0xfc0        ; ???
  400828:   279c673c    addiu   gp,gp,26428 ; ???
  40082c:   0399e021    addu    gp,gp,t9    ; ???

  400830:   27bd8020    addiu   sp,sp,-32736  ; sp -= 0x7fe0 (-32736=0xffff8020)
  400834:   34038670    li  v1,0x8670
  400838:   afbf7fdc    sw  ra,32732(sp)
  40083c:   afbe7fd8    sw  s8,32728(sp)
  400840:   afb77fd4    sw  s7,32724(sp)
  400844:   afb67fd0    sw  s6,32720(sp)
  400848:   afb57fcc    sw  s5,32716(sp)
  40084c:   afb47fc8    sw  s4,32712(sp)
  400850:   afb37fc4    sw  s3,32708(sp)
  400854:   afb27fc0    sw  s2,32704(sp)
  400858:   afb17fbc    sw  s1,32700(sp)
  40085c:   afb07fb8    sw  s0,32696(sp)
  400860:   03a3e823    subu    sp,sp,v1  ; sp-=0x8670 (local space=0x8670 bytes)
  400864:   afbc0018    sw  gp,24(sp)
```

Then at the end of the function it does:

```
  4009e0:   8fbc0018    lw  gp,24(sp)
  4009e4:   34088670    li  t0,0x8670
  4009e8:   03a8e821    addu    sp,sp,t0    ; sp+=0x8670; //remove local space
  4009ec:   8fbf7fdc    lw  ra,32732(sp)
  4009f0:   8fbe7fd8    lw  s8,32728(sp)
  4009f4:   8fb77fd4    lw  s7,32724(sp)
  4009f8:   8fb67fd0    lw  s6,32720(sp)
  4009fc:   8fb57fcc    lw  s5,32716(sp)
  400a00:   8fb47fc8    lw  s4,32712(sp)
  400a04:   8fb37fc4    lw  s3,32708(sp)
  400a08:   8fb27fc0    lw  s2,32704(sp)
  400a0c:   8fb17fbc    lw  s1,32700(sp)
  400a10:   8fb07fb8    lw  s0,32696(sp)
  400a14:   03e00008    jr  ra
  400a18:   27bd7fe0    addiu   sp,sp,32736 ; sp += 0x7fe0
```

Question #1:
Despite searching around for awhile on the internet, I still don't really understand how gp is supposed to be used in the stackframe.

In particular, the documents I read say the call procedure standard is a0-a3 are used as function input, v0-v3 as function output, s0-s8 are preserved across calls, and t0-t9 are not preserved across any call.  So the pushing and popping of s0-s8 make sense.  *But why in the world is it setting gp according to the value in t9!?*

Question #2:
I don't understand why it moves the stack pointer twice.  It seems to reserve local space twice.

And on top of that, the addiu instruction is being disassembled with a *negative* number which doesn't make sense since the 'u' means unsigned, however the code doesn't make sense unless I actually consider it a negative number.  I double checked the opcode by looking it up at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture.  And it is indeed "addiu" and not "addi".  I'm so confused here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first three instructions are for supporting *Position Independent Code*. See [this linux-mips page](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PIC_code) for an excellent explanation of PIC on MIPS. `t9` holds the address of the function, which can change every time you load a library supporting PIC, and that value is added to a constant already in `gp`. Similar to x86's:

```
call __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
add $0x1b88, %ebx
```

Where `__i686.get_pc_thunk.bx` loads `%ebx` with the address of the next instruction, and the subsequent add converts `%ebx` into a point of reference that will be used to access global symbols.

**ADDIU:**
The only difference between signed and unsigned addition on MIPS is that signed addition can raise an overflow exception, so `ADDIU` is used instead to avoid that.

**Several stack adjustments:** These probably relate to the fact that MIPS uses 16-bit immediates, so cannot always adjust the stack in one `ADDIU`.

Comment: So both ADDIU and ADDI sign extend the constant?  So "addiu a0,a0,0x8020" is really like saying a0=a0+0xFFFF8020 ?  This disagrees with wikipedia which says "C is zero-extended" for addiu.  So I want to make sure I understand (maybe someone knowledgeable should change the wikipedia page).

Comment: Yes, ADDIU is defined as `GPR[rt] <- GPR[rs] + sign_extend( immed16)`.

Comment: Thank you thank you!  Since wiki is just plain wrong, is there a clear/concise (and correct) MIPS opcode guide you recomment?

Comment: The specs are at http://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips32/#specifications (registration required, apparently)