# MIPS ADDIU confusion

Tags: mips, processor, instruction-set, pcspim

I am doing an assignment on single cycle MIPS processor and I am a little confused on the addiu instruction.

[On this website](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html), as my reference the author states that the immediate will be sign extened

```
Description:
   Adds a register and a sign-extended immediate value and stores the result
   in a register
Operation:
   $t = $s + imm; advance_pc (4);
Syntax:
   addiu $t, $s, imm
Encoding:
   0010 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

If I have the following instructions

```
   lui      $3,0x1001
   addiu    $3,$3,0x8010
```

and I create my data path that sign extends addiu I would get

```
$3 := 0x1001_0000
$3 := 0x1001_0000 + 0x1111_8010 = 0x1000_8010
```

But it is incorrect according to PCSpim and I should get

```
$3 := 0x1001_8010
```

I am confused why I need to sign extend addiu, from what I understand if I do something like `addiu $1, $1, -10` it should be treated as `addiu $1, $1, 10` because it is unsigned.

So why does it say I should sign-extend the immediate value?

Comment: [`ADDIU` definitely sign-extends the imm16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835724/mips-stack-frame-and-addiu-instruction-confusion#comment8125193_6836242). Are you sure your assembler isn't doing some magic when you write a constant that can't be represented by a sign-extended imm16?  (i.e. `addiu    $3,$3,0x8010` should give a warning that it will actually assemble like `addiu    $3,$3,0xFFFF8010`, not `addiu    $3,$3,0x00008010`

Comment: Also `addiu $1, $1, -10` isn't the same as `addiu $1, $1, 10`.  The [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) 16-bit representation of -10 is `2^16 - 10 = 0xfff6`

Answer (score 1):

In `spim`, the:

```
addiu    $3,$3,0x8010
```

is a pseudo-op and recognized as a desire for *unsigned* addition [by virtue of the `0x`] which the `addiu` *instruction* can't do [because of the sign extension].

So, `spim` generates:

```
ori    $1,$0,0x8010
addu   $3,$3,$1
```

In `mars`, the sequence is:

```
lui    $1,0
ori    $1,$1,0x8010
addu   $3,$3,$1
```

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes. I was going to run the sequence through `mars` anyway [`spim` is more finicky], but I did see your comment, so ... Credit where credit is due ... FYI, I was going to send you a comment at the top, but I figured you'd notice anyway.